# python: pausing a simulation in simpy

Tags: python, queue, simulation, simpy

I was hoping someone could point me a the right direction as i work through building a queue model in Simpy. The documentation and examples on the Simpy site are amazing and i wanted to see if i could build upon an example they provided.

Essentially, i am simulating a process where a clerk has to review paperwork. The paperwork both arrives and exits his queue (i.e. is serviced) at random time intervals (much like an MM1 queue) with a first-in-first-out service discipline.

The tricky part i am finding is that I would like to model the process such that the clerk has to sleep for some period of time before returning to work. For example, if the simulation runs for "4 weeks", the clerk should sleep for 12 hours per day during that period. I cant seem to get this last caveat to function. Please see my code below, thanks!

```
import random

import simpy

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


RANDOM_SEED = 123456 #Random seed
INTERVAL_RECORDS = 30.0  #review records roughly every xx hours?
T_INTER = 28 #generate records roughly every xx hours?
WEEKS = 4
SIM_TIME = WEEKS*7*24*60 #simulation time (hours?)

class record_review:

    def __init__(self, env):
        self.env = env
        self.shift_exchange = env.event()


def record(env, interval, counter, data, t_inter):
        """Source generates records randomly"""
        for i in range(1):
            """start off with x=i records in queue"""
            c = review(env, 'Record%02d' % i, counter, time_in_queue=30.0)
            env.process(c)
            t = random.expovariate(1.0 / interval) #set up random generation     rate 
            yield env.timeout(t)

        while True:
            """continually generate records throughout simulation"""
            yield env.timeout(random.randint(t_inter-2, t_inter+2))   #generate record between +/- 2 of interal
            i += 1
            c = review(env, 'Record%02d' % i, counter, time_in_queue=30.0)
            env.process(c)   
            t = random.expovariate(1.0 / interval) #random generation rate
            yield env.timeout(t)


def review(env, name, counter, time_in_queue):
        """Record arrives, is reviewed and exits."""
        arrive = env.now
        print('%7.4f %s: Record has entered queue' % (arrive, name))

        with counter.request() as req:
            yield req 
            wait = env.now - arrive #total wait time / record
            tib = random.expovariate(1.0 / time_in_queue) #time in  queue/review rate
            yield env.timeout(tib)
            data.append(wait) #monitor
            print('%7.4f %s: Waited %6.3f' % (env.now, name, wait))
            print('%7.4f %s: Finished' % (env.now, name))

def shift_exchange(self, env):

           while True:
               for i in range(SIM_TIME):
                   yield env.timeout(60)
                   self.shift_exchange = env.event()


# Setup and start the simulation
print('Batch Record Review Simulation')
random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)
env = simpy.Environment()
data = []

# Start processes and run
    counter = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)
    env.process(record(env, INTERVAL_RECORDS, counter, data, T_INTER))
    env.run(until=SIM_TIME)
```

Comment: Where is your clear process? If "clerk" is an entity in your model, you should model it as a component of your simulation (e.g., as a process or resource).

Comment: I thought that the "review" function was the process, but I see your point. I was didn't define a resource. Thanks for the input